# MySQL Search within a JSON Array from a Select Statement

Tags: mysql, search, mysql-json

I am new to JSON in MySQL.  I am using MySQL 5.7.

I am attempting to search within a JSON Array for values from another field.

Example.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (jID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, jdoc JSON, PRIMARY KEY(`Jid`));
CREATE TABLE t2 (ID INT);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO t1 (JDOC) VALUES
          ('{"a": 17, "b": "red"}'),
          ('{"a": 17, "b": "red", "x": [3, 5, 7]}');
          
SELECT t1.*, JSON_EXTRACT (jdoc, '$.x') AS A, JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, '$.x'),'3','$') AS B FROM t1;
```

Works as expected.

| jID  |      jdoc      |    A    |    B    |
|------|----------------|---------|---------|
|  1   | {"x": "red"}   |  "red"  |    0    |
|  2   |{"x": [3, 5, 7]}|[3, 5, 7]|    1    |
What I want to run is

```
SELECT t1.*, JSON_EXTRACT (jdoc, '$.x') AS A, 
JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, '$.x'), (SELECT ID FROM t2),'$') AS B FROM t1;
```

However I can't work out how to make this work and get an Invalid Data type as it is expecting a string or int, not "(Select ID from t2)".

However this is just an intermediate step.  What I really want to write is some code that finds all the values in t2.ID that do not exist in x in a passed in JSON Array
`('{"a": 17, "b": "red", "x": [3, 5, 7]}');`

To me this seems a fairly standard request.  I have a Stored Procedure being passed a lot of information, and I need to see if the information already exists in the database, to know what to do with it.  I achieve this by comparing ID values of x against the ID values in a table.

Edit.  The more I think about it, what I'm wanting is the opposite of the JSON_Array call.  Something that converts an array back to a list.

Edit2.  I see you could achieve it with JSON_TABLE in version 8.  Anything in versino 5.7?

Comment: "*Works as expected. <table>*" - the shared output doesn't correspond to your code's output >> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sUySTeW7YPakKroazY195H/0. Are you sure your tables definition is correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have re-written the example to be clearer.  I have also expanded on what I'm trying to achieve at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a stored procedure which converts the array to a list.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Convert_JSON_Array2List`(JArray JSON)
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
DETERMINISTIC

Convert_JSON_Array2List:BEGIN
DECLARE opStringList VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT NULL;

    SET opStringList = NULL;
    
  -- Check valid JSON

  IF ISNULL(JArray) THEN    

    RETURN opStringList;
    LEAVE Convert_JSON_Array2List;

  END IF;

  IF NOT JSON_VALID(JArray) THEN
    
    RETURN opStringList;
    LEAVE Convert_JSON_Array2List;

  END IF;
  
  -- TODO.  Write more checks.
  -- including that this is just a JSON array and not a JSON Object.
  
  -- Calculate Result
SET opStringList := 
  REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
       JArray
       , '['
       , ''
     )
     , ']'
     , ''
   )
   , '"'
   , ''
 );

RETURN opStringList;

END$$
```